# PL/SQL procedure, cursor, where clause

Tags: plsql, cursor, where-clause

i ve got some database with customer id, names, surnames. I made procedure with some parameters, which includes cursor with parameters. And i want with that cursor show customer names, surnames, id. And i want show that, where i call procedure, and i for example write as parameters in procedure for example NULL NULL, it show me all record. Next if i write NULL, Surname, it show me records with that surnames. If i write firstname,NULL, it show record only records with that first name and if i write Firstname,lastname, it show me only that record which matching this. So my procedure works fine, but i need right where clause n cursor. This is my cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_two(c_f_name VARCHAR2,c_l_name VARCHAR2) IS

CURSOR c2(f_name VARCHAR2,l_name VARCHAR2) IS
 SELECT cus_id,cus_l_name,cus_f_name
 FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE (cus_f_name IS NOT NULL AND (cus_f_name = f_name orcus_l_name
 IS NULL)) 
  AND   (cus_l_name IS NOT NULL AND (cus_l_name = l_name or cus_f_name IS
 NULL));
  v_complex   c2%ROWTYPE;
 lv_show   VARCHAR2(20);
 f_name    VARCHAR2(20) := c_f_name;
 l_name    VARCHAR2(20) := c_l_name;

BEGIN
  open c2(f_name,l_name);
  LOOP
  FETCH c2 INTO v_complex;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_complex.cus_id|| ' ' ||v_complex.cus_f_name|| ' '   
 ||v_complex.cus_l_name);
  EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;

END LOOP;
 CLOSE c2;
END;
```

EVERYTHING IS IFNE IN THAT PROCEDURE BUT I NEED ONLY RIGHT WHERE CLAUSE! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `LIKE` and `NVL`.

```
 WHERE cus_f_name LIKE NVL(c_f_name, '%')
   AND cus_l_name LIKE NVL(c_l_name, '%');
```

Explanation:

The function `NVL` returns the first parameter if it is not `NULL`.
Otherwise it returns the second parameter.

Comment: Not Work, only for Firstname,lastname

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted according to your question? Be able to search after first- and lastname? What else do you need?

Comment: I need if i write test_two(NULL,'surname') it show me record which matching with thath sruname, if i write test_two('firstname',NULL) it show me record which matching with that firstname,if I write  test_two(NULL,NULL) it show me all record and if I write  test_two('firstname','Jurica') it show me again matching record

Comment: Alright so i got that correct. I haven't tested this code but it should work. What is the problem you experience? Are there any records shown if you call `test_two(NULL, NULL);`? Or is there an error message when you try to compile it?

Comment: I just saw that you are using `dbms_output.put_line`. Don't forget to enable the server output  with `set serveroutput on` before you call the procedure

Comment: sorry, i explained litle bit wrong, if my procedure parameters will have value null null, so i wrote nothing, it show me everything, if write nothing only t o frst name it show me records matching with surname, and i write nothing in surname parameter and somethiung in firstname it show me records with matching to firstname parameter. You got me ? for example

Comment: test_one('','Jurica'} it show me three records id,firstname,surname where surname is jurica, bbut if test_two('','') it show every recrod from my table

Comment: Hmm okay but it should do that since an empty string is equal to `NULL` in PL/SQL. Tell me please what your result is when you execute `test_two('', '');` otherwise I'm not able to help you.

Comment: Alright are you sure that you have enabled the server output with the command `set serveroutput on;`before calling the procedure? Can you show me how you call the procedure?

Comment: i am using pl/sql developer, so i don t need set serveroutput on;